# How to get the final URL after multiple types of redirects?

Tags: php, url, redirect

what i try to find is the final URL from a local price comparison site, Pricy.ro.

Example URL: https://www.pricy.ro/extensionhtml?url=https://www.emag.ro/telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-12-128gb-5g-black-mgja3rm-a/pd/DZDJ27MBM/

From this i parse the URL's from HTML as an array:

```
$shops = [
['shop' => 'emag', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60e6d3aec716012740f624a6&source=AlternativeProducts'],
['shop' => 'altex', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60ca3252c0486fc28847794b&source=AlternativeProducts'],
['shop' => 'mediagalaxy', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60cb38efc0486fc2884ba1a1&source=AlternativeProducts'],
['shop' => 'flanco', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60c9ca58c0486fc288336be3&source=AlternativeProducts'],
['shop' => 'evomag', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60a8f6e0a771b2fb18843424&source=AlternativeProducts'],
['shop' => 'pcgarage', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60a8f6e0a771b2fb18843424&source=AlternativeProducts'],
];
```

With this PHP code:

```
function url_redir($url, $maxRequests = 10){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $maxRequests);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Custom Link Checker)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close ($ch);
    
    return $url;
}

foreach ($shops as $shop) {
echo 'Shop: ' . $shop['shop'] . ' url: ' . url_redir($shop['url']) . '<br/>';}
```

With this i manage to get only one url output:

```
Shop: itgalaxy url: https://app.profitshare.ro/l/8161510/?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.itgalaxy.ro%2Ftelevizoare%2Fsamsung%2Fled-smart-tv-ue43tu7172uxxh-109cm-ultra-hd-4k-grey-353802%2F
Shop: vexio url: https://www.pricy.ro/
Shop: ideall url: https://www.pricy.ro/
Shop: emag url: https://www.pricy.ro/
Shop: flanco url: https://www.pricy.ro/
```

I don't get any solution to get the final url if the redirect is made via javascript?

Do i have a better solution without curl, regex and stuff like this, i've read about headless browser?

This is the reason why i am looking for another solution. In my case a 200 header response does not mean - final URL.

Comment: You are not closing the handle $verbose, neither closing curl session using curl_close(). Try closing those inside the loop. For every shop initialize a new curl session and use a different $verbose handle.. That should do the trick.. Also yes curl redirect follow will stop as soon as it will get a 200 response. So after 200 if there is any JS based redirect, you wont get it using CURL.

Comment: Maybe you could inspire yourself from the curl -L, --location (Follow redirects flag) combined with -vvv to get what you seek for..

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with PHP Curl and Regex but it may be overly complicated (every time you have a code 200 you will have to parse js scripts and download and parse js assets, and if you find a redirect, load the new page and repeat).

I gave it a try with an headless browser (chromium + PHP library) and it seems to work without too many difficulties:

```
// PHP code
use HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory;
use HeadlessChromium\Page;

$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory('chromium-browser');
$browserFactory->addOptions(['customFlags' => ['--no-sandbox']]);
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser();

$shops = [
    ['shop' => 'emag', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60e6d3aec716012740f624a6&source=AlternativeProducts'],
    ['shop' => 'altex', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60ca3252c0486fc28847794b&source=AlternativeProducts'],
    ['shop' => 'mediagalaxy', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60cb38efc0486fc2884ba1a1&source=AlternativeProducts'],
    ['shop' => 'flanco', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60c9ca58c0486fc288336be3&source=AlternativeProducts'],
    ['shop' => 'evomag', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60a8f6e0a771b2fb18843424&source=AlternativeProducts'],
    ['shop' => 'pcgarage', 'url' => 'https://www.pricy.ro/red/r/?shopProductId=60a8f6e0a771b2fb18843424&source=AlternativeProducts'],
];

$page = $browser->createPage();
foreach ($shops as $shop) {
    $page->navigate($shop['url'])->waitForNavigation(Page::LOAD);
    $evaluation = $page->evaluate('window.location.href');
    $value = $evaluation->getReturnValue();
    echo 'Shop: ' . $shop['shop'] . ' url: ' . $value . '<br/>';
}
```

output:

```
Shop: emag url: https://www.emag.ro/telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-12-128gb-5g-black-mgja3rm-a/pd/DZDJ27MBM/
Shop: altex url: https://altex.ro/telefon-apple-iphone-12-5g-128gb-black/cpd/SMTIP121BK/
Shop: mediagalaxy url: https://mediagalaxy.ro/telefon-apple-iphone-12-5g-128gb-black/cpd/SMTIP121BK/
Shop: flanco url: https://www.flanco.ro/telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-12-5g-128gb-black.html?click_code=221057d7f76218a4c3e00db6497588f5&utm_source=profitshare.ro&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=P5R&utm_content=app.profitshare.ro
Shop: evomag url: https://www.evomag.ro/solutii-mobile-telefoane-mobile/apple-telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-12-super-retina-xdr-oled-6.1-128gb-flash-camera-duala-12-12-mp-wi-fi-5g-ios-negru-3800891.html?utm_source=2parale&utm_medium=quicklink&utm_campaign=bb3110552&2pau=bb3110552&2ptt=quicklink&2ptu=d4f678b43&2prp=fFbjvV35Z7yScpkQPfniFCE8qlh3nr4oX0yix4xvMe1wkVIOzDh3anGs13eRqso-tPaQNa3yq5OsXAyQr8BI0rVKz5ICNj1uCm3hm_H52uEfXXId9WyWnozrTXwVyVB0QrHC5dl-_NXNLZXq1i0qiQ&2pdlst=
Shop: pcgarage url: https://www.evomag.ro/solutii-mobile-telefoane-mobile/apple-telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-12-super-retina-xdr-oled-6.1-128gb-flash-camera-duala-12-12-mp-wi-fi-5g-ios-negru-3800891.html?utm_source=2parale&utm_medium=quicklink&utm_campaign=bb3110552&2pau=bb3110552&2ptt=quicklink&2ptu=d4f678b43&2prp=KFYuuZuHQ4p1BMOAOYbwHFgPJZ8u-LMt9dRHup5OgdCD3ZDnjUpZIc3owzV_FrdiPr2EXpTy3-_BQTxicHqVCvDLGkcDYGc3ndeo_euYPnMOtc8Bvj-Kkr9ncgAniDlRblY0N0oCVDN-4GHFZQe1NQ&2pdlst=
```

For this code to work I had to install the `Chrome PHP` library https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome

```
composer require chrome-php/chrome
```

And I also had to install chromium on my server, depending where you run your code it could not be feasable.

The paramters I used to customize my `BrowserFactory` instance are linked to my chromium installation and may be different for you.

The result URLs seems correct, but the script may take too long to execute for your taste. The `Chrome PHP` library offers various options that could help with performances.